# Hibernate @OneToOne unidirectional relation from "weak" entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cascading-deletes

I have a User and ActivationKey entities.
The ActivationKey entity refers to a User entity created when the user is created and it's deleted once the user has visited a link that has been sent to his e-mail.

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    ...
}

public class ActivationKey {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Usuario usuario;

    ...
}
```

The thing is: when I delete de activation key, the user is also deleted because of the cascade.

Is there a way to avoid this but keep the automatic deletion the other way around, meaning that if a User gets deleted that hasn't been activated, it automatically deletes the corresponding ActivationKey before deleting the user (because of the FK)?

If I remove the (cascade = CascadeType.ALL) then when I try to delete a User that hasn't been activated, it fails because of the FK.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenario, you should declare the bidirectional relationship . You should also specify `@OneToOne` in `User` class as :

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true,mappedBy="usuario")
private ActivationKey activationKey;
```

Here you are basically specifying that `User` is parent entity for `ActivationKey` and you are specifying that for every action on `User`, same action should be taken on `ActivationKey` while vice versa may not be true(that will depend on the cascading type in `ActivationKey`). `mappedBy` attribute specifies that in child entity you will find the instance of parent entity by the value of this attribute.

In `ActivationKey` class, remove `cascade` type:

```
 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
 private Usuario usuario;
```

Here since you are not mentioning any cascading type, thus, the operation performed on `ActivationKey` **alone** will not show any impact on the parent `User` object.

Comment: So there's no way to avoid the bidirectional relationship? It's kind of useless once the user has been activated.

Comment: As per the scenarios mentioned by you, I don't think there is any other solution